# Getting error while running exe created by cx_freeze

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I have converted my Python script into an exe file, it works perfectly on my machine, I installed it in a different machine which doesn't have Python in it.
I get this error message while running the exe.

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__start
up__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console
.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "Text.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 18,
 in <module>
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

setup.py:

```
import sys,os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import matplotlib

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

setup( name = "Text Analyzer" , version = "0.1" , description = "Test Case Analyzer" , executables = [Executable("Text.py"),Executable("Text_Get.py")]  )
```

The machine does not have Python so why it is referring to the `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` path.

Please help.

Comment: why you do not use pyinstaller?

Comment: updated with setup.py

Comment: @FredrickBrennan , can you check

Comment: @bmacnaughton , can you help me to fix it

Comment: `build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"], "packages": ["numpy"]}`

Answer (score 0):

Since *init*.py in panda check for hard dependency it throws error.
to fix this add numpy in packages list.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","numpy"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}